# Python script to retrieve lowest number of combinations

Tags: python, combinations

I've just started learning Python and found this `itertools` module very interesting.
I just can't figure out a logic to solve following problem:

> Given a set of combinations (say of letters), find out the shortest number of combinations (of n length of elements) that would match them all. In the following example, all combinations of 5 letters would have matches, but 1 and 6 would be enough to cover all letters.

[image: example]

Can any expert help?

I tried looping removing the selected indexes but that won't work as expected.

Comment: Can you add some details of what you've tried, and maybe an example of what you would expect? I see the example but it would help if you could write out what you expect.

Comment: Doing this with itertools will take prohibitively long with a large set, since you'll have to test every set of combinations. You should try to come up with a more analytic approach.

Comment: Your picture suggest `number_of_letters / n` should solve the problem. Can you show an example where this wouldn't work?

Comment: @Barmar, any references on more analytic approaches? Thanks

Comment: No, sorry, dynamic programming is not my area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that does what you are looking for. This uses itertools to generate combinations, and then checks those combinations to see if the cover the entire input set.

```
from itertools import combinations

def checkElementsIn2D(set, charsToMatch):
    for char in charsToMatch:
        found = False
        for subset in set:
            if char in subset:
                found = True
                break
        if not found:
            return False
    return True


def findMinimumSuperset(charsToMatch,charSets):
    # Start with 1 set per check, and increase each iteration.
    # This grantees we will find a solution with the minimum n
    for numSets in range(1,len(charSets)):

        # Generate a list of possible set combinations using itertools
        selectedSets = []
        for combination in combinations(charSets,numSets):
            selectedSets.append(list(combination))
        
        # Check each set, returning if all the elements are contained
        for set in selectedSets:
            if checkElementsIn2D(set,charsToMatch):
                print("Found matching set with num elements of {}: {}".format(numSets,set))
                return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    charsToMatch = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
    charSets = [['a','b','c','d','e'],
                ['b','c','d','e','f'],
                ['c','d','e','f','g'],
                ['d','e','f','g','h'],
                ['e','f','g','h','i'],
                ['f','g','h','i','j']]
    findMinimumSuperset(charsToMatch,charSets)
```

Example output:

```
$ python3 test.py
Found matching set with num elements of 2: [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], ['f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']]
```

Comment: Amazing, @Zico, thanks. I'll study the script.